# Remove a particular item from a list which is in a session

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
List<ShoppingCartView> removeitem = (List<ShoppingCartView>)Session["ShoppingView"];
```

I want to remove a row on clicking that particular product. For example if I click on product xxx and want to remove the product xxx from Session["ShoppingView"], the rest of the list should remain the same.

Comment: how you set `Session["ShoppingView"]`? what is `ShoppingCartView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to edit the condition accordingly

```
var list = (List<ShoppingCartView>)Session["ShoppingView"];
Session["ShoppingView"] = list.Where(x => x.ProductName!= "pname").ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx)

```
Session["ShoppingView"] = (List<ShoppingCartView>)Session["ShoppingView"].Remove((List<ShoppingCartView>)Session["ShoppingView"].Where(x => x.id== sessionItemToRemove).ToList());
```

Comment: ya i tried i even passed the id like this int sessionItemToRemove =Int32.Parse(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("proid")).Text); but getting error in assigning the id to remove from session.i wnt to know how to pass the id of product xx to remove xx from session

Comment: What happens after you refresh the screen after doing this? Does the change then occur? I would consider adding a foreach loop in your code, iterate through all the values just to be certain that the value you are comparing is what you're expecting!

Comment: int sessionItemToRemove =Int32.Parse(((Label)e.Item.FindControl("proid")).Text);           var cart = Session["ShoppingView"] as List<ShoppingCartView>;  cart.Remove(sessionItemToRemove);  THE REMOVE IS showing error during runtime

Comment: The type passed to remove has to be the type of your list. If you have a list defined as `List<T>` then Remove has to be passed an object of type `T`. In this case you are trying to remove a string from a list of ShoppingCartView objects which it is not happy about.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
List<string> foo =  Session["ShoppingView"];  
foo.Remove("xxx");  
Session["ShoppingView"] = foo;
```